# exec() PHP cannot wait the response (phpseclib)

Tags: php, shell, ssh, exec, phpseclib

I just try to use `exec()` command but it's not work (I use phpseclib).
This is my code

```
echo $ssh->exec("cd testpath; ./display_test.sh 1 -s 098888888");
```

and the result is

> egrep: can't open /testpath/test_displaysub.10912.mml

But when I run with read(), write() with this code

```
$ssh->setTimeout(5);
$ssh->read();
$ssh->write("cd testpath \n");
$ssh->read();
$ssh->write("./display_test.sh 1 -s 098888888 \n");
echo $ssh->read();
```

It works. I want to use the command `exec()` because it doesn't use timeout.
I think that exec() command is error like that it may be that it not wait for the response or skip some command in that file `(./display_test.sh)` because it my code that have

```
sendCommand (){
    cat $templateLogout >> ${FILE}
    $scriptfile < ${FILE} 1> $processfile 2> tmp #led $processfile to run other
}

checkTimeout(){
    timeout=$(grep "Timed out" tmp|wc -l)
    if [ $timeout -gt 0 ]
    then
        Result="Connection Lost."
        index_timeout=1
    fi
    rm tmp
}

getResult (){
    Result= egrep "response" $mmlfile .........(have more)
```

When I use `exec()` it create $processfile but in $processfile is not wait for complete running then it skip to do `checkTimeout()` and `getResult ()` that the reason why it cannot egrep I think like that.
If I think wrong please tell me.

And please tell me that what should I do with this problem if I want to use command `exec()`.

Note!
I really don't use the timeout because my project can input with the file and I don't know how many time that process want to do
In my file can be

```
0988888888
0988888887
0988888886
```

and my scrript also  `./display_test.sh 1 -f filename \n`

Comment: `$ssh->write("cd cd testpath \n");` Is this the actual line in your "working" code? This line would fail, so the following command would execute in a different working directory from what you probably expect.

Comment: So sorry I actually use "cd testpath \n" but I typing wrong. What should I do for this problem that exec() doesn't wait my response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use timeout with read() / write(). Instead try this:

```
$ssh->read('[prompt]');
$ssh->write("cd testpath \n");
$ssh->read('[prompt]');
$ssh->write("./display_test.sh 1 -s 098888888 \n");
echo $ssh->read('[prompt]');
```

`[prompt]` is a placeholder - use whatever your actual prompt is.

W.r.t. `$ssh->exec`...  maybe try to do `$ssh->enablePTY(); $ssh->exec(); echo $ssh->read()`.

Comment: I try to follow your suggestion but if I use `"[prompt]" without "timeout"` it still running the output doesn't come out or Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded. And I try this one that you suggest me 
`$ssh->enablePTY(); 
echo $ssh->exec("cd testpath; ./display_test.sh 1 -s 098888888");`
this not work too because the output came out "1" What should I do. Thank you so so much.

Comment: I really don't use the timeout because my project can input with the file and I don't know how many time that process want to do
In my file can be
0988888888
0988888887
0988888886
and my scrript also  ./display_test.sh 1 -f filename \n

Comment: @pinkypink - try `echo $ssh->read()` after `$ssh->exec()`. The `$ssh->read()` shouldn't block there sine the output does end. This is in contrast to an interactive shell where the output kinda doesn't end. That said, w.r.t. `"[prompt]" without "timeout"`...  humor me this. What *is* your prompt? On my system it's `[ec2-user@neubert ~]$`. Did you replace the `[prompt]` placeholder?

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion. I can do it with command read write without timeout but the command exec() I use $ssh->enablePTY(); $ssh->exec("cd testpath; ./display_test.sh 1 -s 098888888"); echo $ssh->read(); but it have the same result with only command exec() . Did you have another suggestion for this if you have please let me know because if I use read write I must to change [prompt] every time. thank you.

Comment: @neubert What if [prompt] value changes during process - say like timing prompt ?

Comment: @BartmanDilaw - if it changes in a predictable way you could adapt the `$ssh->read()` parameter appropriately. Otherwise I guess you could do `$ssh->setTimeout(3)` or something and do `$ssh->read()` without any parameters. I mean, at the end of the day, phpseclib is providing a simulation of an interactive shell - there's only so much that can be done. Like if you type in the prompt into a text file and then do `vim prompt.txt`...  phpseclib would think that the system is expecting input when it actually isn't. I could see people even being fooled by that one lol

Comment: @neubert I cannot set $ssh->setTimeout(3) because shell stops after the 3 seconds...
My solution :
1/ Setting Unix constant in .bash_profile with non functionnal value
eg : export _DO_EXIT_SSH_="IWillNeverSeeThat"
2/ in PhpSecLib PHP code, adding "echo $_DO_EXIT_SSH_" to original command
$cmd = $cmd . "; echo $_DO_EXIT_SSH_" 
3/ waiting to "read" then "IWillNeverSeeThat" value.
$ssh->read("IWillNeverSeeThat");
This works fine !